# FitNEsse versions 20110104 and later - how much faster?

Tags: fitnesse

I'm trying to convince my management to upgrade to the new version of FitNesse (we're running 20070619 now)
I saw a message by Uncle Bob at the yahoo group

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/fitnesse/message/16752

saying that's "It is *much* faster." - but I was wondering if anybody has any metrics, how faster it is comparing to the old one? 
thanks! O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Slim or Fit style tables?  How large are the pages? We saw a significant improvement when the parser was rewritten. The old parser was regex based and got slow on big pages.  The new parser is a more proper parser and is much more efficient.

If I had to put a specific number on it, I would say it was 40+ percent faster, but your milage may vary based on how your tests are written.

All that said, there are a lot of great features in the newer versions.  Though if you're using a 2007 version, most of those improvements are related to Slim, which was introduced after 2007. The parser improvements will be there, and a couple of other updates you might enjoy (Test History, Templates, new Theming capabilities, etc).

Comment: 40+ percent sounds great! Some of our pages are big; We don't use that many tables (Fit style), we use many fixtures of our own and those of FitLibrary. I do see lots of new interesting features in the newer versions; hope we will eventually get to use them. Thanks a lot!